# How to compare two tables in oracle when number of columns in tables differs

Tags: oracle

I have two tables in my database they are EXP1 and EXP2. I tried with the below query, this query is working when both the tables have same number of columns but my table EXP1 has 1000 columns n EXP2 has 1000+4.

```
select *
from 
(
    (select * from exp1
     minus 
     select * from exp2)
    union all
    (select * from exp2
     minus
     select * from exp1)
);
```

Comment: Man, use a column list (common part of all columns of those two tables) instead of *

Comment: for what I'm aware, tables must be union-compatible.. that meaning same set of columns.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: if one my table have  1000 columns and other have 1000+4.. it will be difficult for me to add all the matching columns names in query itself.....is there any query  to exclude that four columns which are different.?..........

Comment: You can query the USER_TAB_COLUMNS or all_tab_columns table for table columns

Comment: You cannot have more than 1000 columns in a table. Thus it will be indeed difficult for you to add all the matching column names.

Comment: You must be using a future version of Oracle; as Wenfried has already observed, Oracle (up to the current version, 12) has a LIMIT of 1000 columns. Or are these not Oracle tables?

Comment: I mean to say my table have many columns and rows .....I have just taken thousand as an example........anyway tnx for your information :)

Answer (score 1):

INTRO: *Below I show how one can do "by hand" what the tools (SQL Developer for example) can do much faster and much better. My interest in this (and yours!) is two-fold: learn and use some ideas that can help in many other problems; and understand what those tools do under the hood in the first place.*

OK. Suppose you have two tables, and they have many columns in common (possibly not in the same order) and a few columns may be different - there may be a handful of columns in one table but not in the other. First you want to be able to look just at the common columns.

Then, suppose that's done. Now what's left of the two tables has many rows in common, but there are a few that are different. A row may exist in one table but not in the other, or two rows, one from each table, may be very similar but they may differ in just one or a small number of column values. Logically these are still one row in the first table but not the second, and the other row only in the second table but not in the first. However, let's say both tables have the same PK column - then you may have the same PK value in both tables, but at least one of the OTHER columns has different values for that PK value in the two tables. And, you want to find these differences between the two tables.

In what follows I will assume that if two columns, in the two tables, have the same name, they will also have the same data type. If that is not guaranteed in your case, it can be fixed with a little more work in the part where I identify the "common columns" - instead of matching them just by name, from the catalog views, they would have to be matched also by data type.

When you get to comparing rows in the two tables in the final step, `(A minus B) union all (B minus A)` works, but is not very efficient. Each table is read twice, and `minus` is an expensive operator. The more efficient solution, which I illustrate below, was discussed in a long thread on AskTom several years ago. Namely: collect all the rows from both tables (with `union all`), group by all the columns, and disregard the groups that have a count of 2. This means rows that were found in both tables, so they are duplicates in the `union all`! Actually, you will see a small additional trick to identify from which table the "non-duplicated" rows come. Add a column for "table_name" and in the final select, after grouping and keeping the groups with `count(*) = 1`, select `max(table_name)`. You need an aggregate function (like `max()`) because you are grouping, but for these rows each group only has one row, so the `max()` is really just the table name.

The beauty of this approach is that it can be used to identify the common columns, too! In that case, we will compare rows from the `USER_TAB_COLS` view - we select column names that appear in either of the tables, and keep only the column names that are duplicates (so the column names appear in both tables). In that part of the solution, I also retrieve `column_id`, which is used to order the columns. Don't worry if you are not familiar with `keep (dense_rank first...)` - it's not really that complicated, but it's not that important either.

First let's set up a test case. I copy the `EMP` table from the `SCOTT` schema to my own schema, I replicate it (so now I have two copies, named `EMP1` and `EMP2`), and I modify them slightly. I delete a different column from each, I delete a few (different) rows from each, and I modify one salary in one table. I will not show the resulting (slightly different) tables, but if you are following along, just `select *` from both and compare them before you continue reading.

Create the tables:

```
create table EMP1 as select * from scott.emp;
Table EMP1 created.

select * from EMP1;

EMPNO ENAME      JOB        MGR HIREDATE              SAL   COMM  DEPTNO
----- ---------- --------- ---- ------------------- ----- ------ -------
 7369 SMITH      CLERK     7902 1980-12-17 00:00:00   800             20
 7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN  7698 1981-02-20 00:00:00  1600    300      30
 7521 WARD       SALESMAN  7698 1981-02-22 00:00:00  1250    500      30
 7566 JONES      MANAGER   7839 1981-04-02 00:00:00  2975             20
 7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN  7698 1981-09-28 00:00:00  1250   1400      30
 7698 BLAKE      MANAGER   7839 1981-05-01 00:00:00  2850             30
 7782 CLARK      MANAGER   7839 1981-06-09 00:00:00  2450             10
 7788 SCOTT      ANALYST   7566 1987-04-19 00:00:00  3000             20
 7839 KING       PRESIDENT      1981-11-17 00:00:00  5000             10
 7844 TURNER     SALESMAN  7698 1981-09-08 00:00:00  1500      0      30
 7876 ADAMS      CLERK     7788 1987-05-23 00:00:00  1100             20
 7900 JAMES      CLERK     7698 1981-12-03 00:00:00   950             30
 7902 FORD       ANALYST   7566 1981-12-03 00:00:00  3000             20
 7934 MILLER     CLERK     7782 1982-01-23 00:00:00  1300             10
```

Modify them slightly:

```
create table EMP2 as select * from EMP1;
Table EMP2 created.

alter table emp1 drop column hiredate;
Table EMP1 altered.

alter table emp2 drop column comm;
Table EMP2 altered.

delete from EMP1 where ename like 'A%';
2 rows deleted;

delete from EMP2 where sal >= 3000;
3 rows deleted

update EMP2 set sal = 2950 where empno = 7698;
1 row updated

commit;
```

At this point you would do well to `select * from EMP1;` and `select * from EMP2;` and compare.

Now let's find out what columns the two tables have left in common.

```
select column_name, 
       min(column_id) keep(dense_rank first order by table_name) as col_id
from   user_tab_cols
where  table_name in ('EMP1', 'EMP2')
group by column_name
having count(*) = 2
order by col_id;

COLUMN_NAME COL_ID
----------- ------
EMPNO            1
ENAME            2
JOB              3
MGR              4
SAL              5
DEPTNO           7

 6 rows selected
```

Perfect, so now we can compare the two tables, but only after we "project" them along the common columns only.

```
select max(table_name) as table_name, EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, SAL, DEPTNO
from (
       select 'EMP1' as table_name, EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, SAL, DEPTNO from EMP1
       union all
       select 'EMP2' as table_name, EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, SAL, DEPTNO from EMP2
     )
group by EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, SAL, DEPTNO
having count(*) = 1
order by EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, SAL, DEPTNO, table_name;

TABLE_NAME EMPNO ENAME      JOB          MGR    SAL   DEPTNO
---------- ----- ---------- --------- ------ ------ --------
EMP2        7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN    7698   1600       30
EMP1        7698 BLAKE      MANAGER     7839   2850       30
EMP2        7698 BLAKE      MANAGER     7839   2950       30
EMP1        7788 SCOTT      ANALYST     7566   3000       20
EMP1        7839 KING       PRESIDENT          5000       10
EMP2        7876 ADAMS      CLERK       7788   1100       20
EMP1        7902 FORD       ANALYST     7566   3000       20

 7 rows selected
```

The output is pretty much what we needed. Notice the first column, which tells us where the "unpaired" row comes from; and note BLAKE, who has different salary in the two tables (and the first column helps us to see what salary he has in which table).

This looks perfect so far, but what to do when you have 1000 columns? You could put it together in C or Java etc., using the result from the "common columns" query above - or you could do it all in Oracle, with dynamic SQL.

As far as I know, there is no set limit on the length of the text of an SQL statement in Oracle; the documentation says *"The limit on how long a SQL statement can be depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space, and memory"* (and probably on your Oracle version, which they didn't mention). In any case, it will be more than 4000 characters, so we need to work with CLOB. In particular, we can't use `listagg()` - we need a workaround. I use `xmlagg()` below. Then, the documentation says if you concatenate text and at least one operand is CLOB the result will be CLOB; if that doesn't work for you, you may have to wrap the smaller text fragments within `to_clob()`. The "dynamic SQL" query below will produce the full text of the query I used above; you will simply copy it and paste it back into your front-end and execute it. You may have to delete wrapping double-quotes or such, depending on your front-end and settings.

First here is how we can create a (potentially very long) string, the list of common column names, which is repeated five times in the final query - just look again at the "final query" we used to compare the two tables above.

```
with
     common_cols ( column_name, col_id ) as (
       select column_name, 
              min(column_id) keep(dense_rank first order by table_name) as col_id
       from   user_tab_cols
       where  table_name in ('EMP1', 'EMP2')
       group by column_name
       having count(*) = 2
     ),
     col_string ( str ) as (
       select rtrim(xmlcast(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, column_name, ', ') order by col_id)
                                                    as clob), ', ') from common_cols
     ) 
select * from col_string;

STR
-----------------------------------
EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, SAL, DEPTNO
```

And finally the full dynamic SQL query (the result is exactly the query I used to compare `EMP1` and `EMP2` on their common columns earlier):

```
with
     common_cols ( column_name, col_id ) as (
       select column_name, 
              min(column_id) keep(dense_rank first order by table_name) as col_id
       from   user_tab_cols
       where  table_name in ('EMP1', 'EMP2')
       group by column_name
       having count(*) = 2
     ),
     col_string ( str ) as (
       select rtrim(xmlcast(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, column_name, ', ') order by col_id) 
                                                    as clob), ', ') from common_cols
     )
select 'select max(table_name) as table_name, ' || str                 || chr(10) ||
       'from ('                                                        || chr(10) ||
       '       select ''EMP1'' as table_name, ' || str || ' from EMP1' || chr(10) ||
       '       union all'                                              || chr(10) ||
       '       select ''EMP2'' as table_name, ' || str || ' from EMP2' || chr(10) ||
       '     )'                                                        || chr(10) ||
       'group by ' || str                                              || chr(10) ||
       'having count(*) = 1'                                           || chr(10) ||
       'order by ' || str || ', table_name;'  as comp_sql_str
from   col_string;
```